# pnpm list -g shows some packages as "not saved", what does it mean?

Tags: pnpm

❯ pnpm list -g

Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

/home/mechell/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/pnpm-global/4

dependencies:
nodemon 2.0.4
pnpm 5.3.0

not saved (you should add these dependencies to package.json if you need them):

**@types/color-name** *link:node_modules/.pnpm/@types/color-name@1.1.1/node_modules/@types/color-name%*

So what does this mean? When installing typescript as global have more of these and I'm not sure if it's missing it and will it break something...

Answer (score 1):

It means that these packages are installed on your system but not listed in a `package.json` dependency list. It can happen if the shamefully-hoist option is used (for compatibility reasons) or if npm or yarn installs something - without you knowing - whilst you are using pnpm.

If you do not want to see these "not saved" packages - as I've seen no option pertaining to this in the source code of pnpm - you can do this:
`pnpm ls | awk '/^not saved/{stop=1} stop==0{print}'`

this will only work on unix/linux based systems, and the awk command will basically remove every line after the one that starts with "not saved".

You can alias it to `pnpmls` in your ~/.bash_profile or similar and then you only ever have to type pnpmls.
`alias pnpmls='pnpm ls | awk "/^not saved/{stop=1} stop==0{print}"'`

I am adding it to my bash_profile right now ;)